# Move image from end of snake in game to front first coordinate in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, pygame, head, coordinate

This is my final project for my Python class.  It's basically a snake game, only it's themed so instead of a snake, there is a leading image (the head) and a train behind it (the snake body).

Everything is perfect in the code, except one thing: the way the code is now, the head is at the end of the snake and I can't figure out for the life of me how to move it to the front where it leads the train.

Here is my code:

Comment: capitalization; formatting

Comment: where is the code? is there a reason why you delete the code?

Comment: someone uploaded it to some website where it has been downloaded 200 times....this question has been resolved. i still have another question posted I need help with if you are interested in giving me some advice. the issue isn't high priority because now i want to have to players on two screens and am embarking on that journey next   8 {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your code, and I change a little in the `drawCock` function:

```
def drawCock(Cock):

    for place in Cock:
        x = place['x'] * size
        y = place['y'] * size
        CART = pygame.transform.scale(image2,(size,size))
        SHOW.blit(CART,(x,y))

    if Cock[2:]:

        HEAD = pygame.transform.scale(image1,(size,size))
        SHOW.blit(HEAD,(Cock[0]['x']*size,Cock[0]['y']*size))
```

I use the dictionary `Cock`'s first item's `x` and `y` as the coordinate values to draw the head. The head is in the first position of the snake now. Hope it helps.